# gcc build fails due a warning in libcpp

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

I am trying to compile the gcc compiler with GCC version >= 12 and when I ran `make` I got the following error

```
tti -I../../../../gittea/gcc/libcpp -I.
-I../../../../gittea/gcc/libcpp/../include
-I../../../../gittea/gcc/libcpp/include    -c -o expr.o -MT expr.o
-MMD -MP -MF .deps/expr.Tpo ../../../../gittea/gcc/libcpp/expr.cc
../../../../gittea/gcc/libcpp/expr.cc: In function ‘unsigned int
cpp_classify_number(cpp_reader*, const cpp_token*, const char**,
location_t)’:
../../../../gittea/gcc/libcpp/expr.cc:842:35: error: format not a
string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  842 |             cpp_warning_with_line (pfile, CPP_W_LONG_LONG,
virtual_location,
      |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  843 |                                    0, message);
      |                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../gittea/gcc/libcpp/expr.cc:845:38: error: format not a
string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  845 |             cpp_pedwarning_with_line (pfile, CPP_W_LONG_LONG,
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  846 |                                       virtual_location, 0, message);
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../gittea/gcc/libcpp/expr.cc:855:33: error: format not a
string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  855 |           cpp_warning_with_line (pfile, CPP_W_SIZE_T_LITERALS,
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  856 |                                  virtual_location, 0, message);
      |                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../gittea/gcc/libcpp/expr.cc:867:42: error: format not a
string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  867 |                 cpp_pedwarning_with_line (pfile, CPP_W_C11_C2X_COMPAT,
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  868 |                                           virtual_location, 0, message);
      |                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../gittea/gcc/libcpp/expr.cc:870:39: error: format not a
string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  870 |                 cpp_warning_with_line (pfile, CPP_W_C11_C2X_COMPAT,
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  871 |                                        virtual_location, 0, message);
      |                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../gittea/gcc/libcpp/expr.cc:877:35: error: format not a
string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  877 |               cpp_error_with_line (pfile, CPP_DL_PEDWARN,
virtual_location, 0,
      |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  878 |                                    message);
      |                                    ~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: some warnings are being treated as errors
```

I have the feeling that I am missing something because this code
has not been touched since 2012 (thank git blame)
so I am pretty sure that I am missing something, but not sure what.

I am also building this within a nix-shell, so my dependencies are

```hs
{
  description = "gcc compiler";

  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
      in {
        packages = {
          default = pkgs.gnumake;
        };
        formatter = pkgs.nixpkgs-fmt;

        devShell = pkgs.mkShell {
          buildInputs = [
            pkgs.gnumake
            pkgs.gcc13

            pkgs.libgcc
            pkgs.glibc

            pkgs.gmp
            pkgs.libmpc
            pkgs.mpfr
            pkgs.flex
            pkgs.bison

            pkgs.isl
            pkgs.pkg-config
            pkgs.autoconf-archive
            pkgs.autoconf
            pkgs.automake
          ];
        };
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I know and I am building it outside of the src, I think also I have all the dependencies enabled but there is something strange that it is going on. My arch machine is able to build it. BTW my build machine is running on NixOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how nix/NixOS build the package! More information on this issue https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/18995

This took me a while but I found a problem with the help of
Some GCC guru.

Some compiler flags are enabled by default with nix, which can cause
hard time for people who work with low-level stuff.

However, the solution is pretty simple. All Nix users need to specify `hardeningDisable`.

In my case, I just disabled the flake file `hardeningDisable = [ "all" ];`

Full solution

---

```hs
{
  description = "gcc compiler";

  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
      in {
        packages = {
          default = pkgs.gnumake;
        };
        formatter = pkgs.nixpkgs-fmt;

        devShell = pkgs.mkShell {
            hardeningDisable = [ "all" ]; # Disable all hardening flags

            buildInputs = [
            pkgs.gnumake
            pkgs.gcc13

            pkgs.gmp
            pkgs.libmpc
            pkgs.mpfr
            pkgs.flex
            pkgs.bison

            pkgs.isl
            pkgs.pkg-config
            pkgs.autoconf-archive
            pkgs.autoconf
            pkgs.automake
          ];
        };
      }
    );
}
```